# how to lock a file so that other process cannot cat it?

Tags: c, unix, locking, fcntl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct flock fl;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_len = 517; //found the size of the file outside (not best practise, I know)
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    int fd = open("test", O_RDWR);
    if(fd<0)
        perror("open");
    
    fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;
    fl.l_pid = getpid();
    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) < 0)
    {
        perror("fcntl"); //geting fcntl: Invalid argument
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if(fl.l_type != F_UNLCK)
    {
        printf("file has been exclusively locked by process:%u\n",fl.l_pid);
        printf("press enter to release the file\n");
        getchar();
        fl.l_type = F_UNLCK; //file released
    }
}
```

I would like to lock a file (`test`), which contain lorem ipsum (some random text), so that other process could not `cat` it until the currect process release the lock. But which argument passed to `fcntl` is wrong?

EDIT:
After comments I have initialized some members of `fl` variable (see edits), no, despite working. I can still `cat` the locked file `test` in another process... why, when it is locked?

Comment: You're not initializing the flock structure.

Comment: You should exit if `fd < 0`, not continue after calling `perror()`.

Comment: In particular, you didn't fill in the `l_start`, `l_len`, and `l_whence` fields of `fl`.

Comment: Read the manual. "record locking, which permits multiple **cooperating** programs to prevent each other from simultaneously accessing parts of a file in error-prone ways". "Remember that file locks are only an advisory protocol for controlling access to a file. There is still potential for access to the file by programs that don’t use the lock protocol." So no, you cannot stop `cat` with this.

Comment: `cat` does not support the advisory lock protocol?

Comment: What do you actually need this for? If you're writing to some file and you don't want anyone to read it until you're done, first write to a temporary file with no read permission for anyone, and when you're done you can move it to the right place and fix the permissions. If something else, please explain.

Comment: @Kevin seems like it is hard question, when you are trying to dodge the original question and only offering indirect solutions, huh?

Comment: @give_me_one What? I want to know what you're trying to do. There's a thing called an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where someone asks how to do Y, because they think that it'll help them do X. But if they just asked how to do X they'd get a better answer. I asked what I did because I want to make sure that isn't the case here.

Comment: Well then without further context, it seems like n. 'pronouns' m's comment is your answer - "no, you cannot stop `cat` with this"

Comment: Instead you can me tell situation *with using the flock structure* (programatically), how to achieve that. And not offering bash-solution with permission. If you have noticed, the question is tagged as `C` not `shell`

Comment: `flock` locks only block other programs that call `flock`. A program that only calls `open`, `read`, and `close` (such as `cat`) will not even notice them. The same is true for `fcntl` locks. In fact, I'm not aware of *any* form of file locking in Unix that will block a call to `open` and/or `read`. In other words, what you want cannot be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File locking is not mandatory locking — it is advisory locking.

That means that if a program such as `cat` does not look to see whether a file is locked, it doesn't matter whether some other program locks it or not — `cat` will still read the file.

Unless you use a variant of `cat` that does check for file locks, you are not going to be able to use file locking to stop `cat`.

What can you do instead?

1. Rename the file.
2. Change permissions on the file.
3. Decide not to worry about it.

The last option is the easiest — and probably most effective.

Some systems do support mandatory file locking.  Typically, that's indicated by setting the SGID bit on a non-executable file.  If you're using such a system, then you should be able to prevent `cat` from working on a locked file.